# exception in SSE programming in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sse, intrinsics

I write these simple C++ codes in visual studio 2012 for SSE programming.But when I run it, an exception accord on

```
void SSE(
          float* pArray1,                   // [in] first source array
          float* pArray2,                   // [in] second source array
          float* pResult,                   // [out] result array
          int nSize)                        // [in] size of all arrays
{
    int nLoop = nSize/ 4; 
    __m128 m1, m2, m3, m4;    
    __m128* pSrc1 = (__m128*) pArray1;
    __m128* pSrc2 = (__m128*) pArray2;
    __m128* pDest = (__m128*) pResult;

    for ( int i = 0; i < nLoop; i++ )
    {
        m1 = _mm_mul_ps(*pSrc1, *pSrc1);        // m1 = *pSrc1 * *pSrc1
        m2 = _mm_mul_ps(*pSrc2, *pSrc2);        // m2 = *pSrc2 * *pSrc2
        m3 = _mm_add_ps(m1, m2);                // m3 = m1 + m2    
        *pDest = m3;                     
        pSrc1++;
        pSrc2++;
        pDest++;
    }
}


int main( int argc, char** argv ) {      
    float* A=new float[20];
    float* B=new float[20];
    float* C=new float[20];     
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        A[i]=B[i]=C[i]=i;       
    }
    SSE(A,B,C,20);    
    cout<<C; 
    return 0;
}
```

exception accord on line that calculated m1 in SSE function.
the exception message is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00CA29BE in SSE.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.
```

Comment: Your arrays are no aligned according to SSE requirements - this is probably undefined behaviour. If the code crashes, you can debug it and see where exactly it crashed. See also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4522/Introduction-to-SSE-Programming

Comment: @user and what exactly solved it? Let the commenters know which of them ended up helping you out the most, after which they can post an answer and you selected it as the solution.